# Loss function not improving

Tags: keras, neural-network

I've been making a classifier using the mnist dataset by following an online tutorial. However, after training the data, my loss function and accuracy doesn't change at all from each epoch. However, I am not getting any error message. Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong? For refrence, my IDE is Jupyter Notebook and I am running Windows 10.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten,Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import to_categorical

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

image_height, image_width = 28, 28
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, image_height*image_width)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, image_height*image_width)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784, )))
model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_grad.py:1424: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:986: The name tf.assign_add is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign_add instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:973: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:2741: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:174: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:181: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:190: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:199: The name tf.is_variable_initialized is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.is_variable_initialized instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\akash\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:206: The name tf.variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer instead.

60000/60000 [==============================] - 13s 222us/step - loss: 14.4960 - acc: 0.1006 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 2/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 246us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 3/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 248us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 4/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 14s 226us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 5/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 14s 238us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 6/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 250us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 7/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 14s 236us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 8/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 13s 214us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 9/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 14s 235us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
Epoch 10/10
60000/60000 [==============================] - 15s 251us/step - loss: 14.5200 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 14.4918 - val_acc: 0.1009
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply picked suboptimal hyperparameters. Try again with 2 or 1 layers of 128 hidden neurons, and since the classes are mutually exclusive, you should use sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

Additionally, the flatten layer can do the reshaping for you. The fit function takes a validation split parameter. Just pass a validation split of 0.2 to the fit function instead of incorrectly using the test data as validation set.

Then evaluate model performance on the model that performs best on validation. Try to include early stopping.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                              min_delta=0.01,
                              patience=10,
                              verbose=2, mode='min')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[es])

model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)
```